# ListView with Image from Json

Tags: android, listview, gson

I have a problem with my application I do, I want to make a listview on ANDROID with pictures taken from GSON. but I wonder how to take text and url for the picture taken by the listview.

GSON

```
[{"brand_city_id":"1","name":"Blue Bird","logo":"http:\/\/gojek.gits.co.id\/uploads\/Blue_Bird1.jpg","description":"Blue bird adalah salah satu member blue bird group, menyediakan jasa taksi dengan harga terjangkau."},{"brand_city_id":"5","name":"Cipaganti","logo":"http:\/\/gojek.gits.co.id\/uploads\/Cipaganti.png","description":"Bertemakan taksimax, Cipaganti Taksi bukan hanya sekedar pengantaran pelanggan di dalam kota, fasilitas lengkap adalah salah satu keunggulan taksimax ini. Dengan fasilitas Wi-Fi dan Movie serta kelengkapan kendaraan yang memadai telah membedakan layanan taksimax dengan taksi yang lainnya."}]
```

and Main.java

```
    package com.gits.pikmiap;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.taxibandung);

        ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, searchResults));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                SearchResults fullObject = (SearchResults)o;
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "You have chosen: " + " " + fullObject.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }  
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

        SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
        sr1.setName("Blue Bird");
        sr1.setDescription("Blue bird adalah salah satu member blue bird group, menyediakan jasa taksi dengan harga terjangkau.");
        sr1.setPhone("214-555-1234");
        sr1.setImage("http://gojek.gits.co.id/uploads/Blue_Bird1.jpg");
        results.add(sr1);

        sr1 = new SearchResults();
        sr1.setName("Cipaganti");
        sr1.setDescription("Bertemakan taksimax, Cipaganti Taksi bukan hanya sekedar pengantaran pelanggan di dalam kota, fasilitas lengkap adalah salah satu keunggulan taksimax ini. Dengan fasilitas Wi-Fi dan Movie serta kelengkapan kendaraan yang memadai telah membedakan layanan taksimax dengan taksi yang lainnya.");
        sr1.setPhone("612-555-0961");
        sr1.setImage("http://gojek.gits.co.id/uploads/cipaganti.ppg");
        results.add(sr1);

        return results;
    }
}
```

SearchResults.java

```
    package com.gits.pikmiap;

public class SearchResults {
     private String name = "";
     private String description = "";
     private String phone = "";
     private String image = "";

     public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
     }

     public String getName() {
      return name;
     }

     public void setDescription(String description) {
      this.description = description;
     }

     public String getDescription() {
      return description;
     }

     public void setPhone(String phone) {
      this.phone = phone;
     }

     public String getPhone() {
      return phone;
     }

     public void setImage(String image) {
          this.image = image;
         }

         public String getImage() {
          return image;
         }
    }
```

MyCustomBaseAdapter.java

```
 package com.gits.pikmiap;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

     private LayoutInflater mInflater;

     public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
      searchArrayList = results;
      mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
     }

     public int getCount() {
      return searchArrayList.size();
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
      return searchArrayList.get(position);
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
     }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ViewHolder holder;
      if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
       holder.txtCityState = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityState);
       holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
       holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

       convertView.setTag(holder);
      } else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }

      holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());
      holder.txtCityState.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
      holder.txtPhone.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getPhone());
      holder.image.setImageURI(null);

      return convertView;
     }

     static class ViewHolder {
     ImageView image;
    TextView txtName;
      TextView txtCityState;
      TextView txtPhone;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GSON that is one solution but you can parse that string without using GSON like on the code mentioned below:

```
String str = "[{\"brand_city_id\": \"1\",\"name\": \"Blue Bird\",\"logo\": \"http://gojek.gits.co.id/uploads/Blue_Bird1.jpg\",\"description\": \"Blue bird adalah salah satu member blue bird group, menyediakan jasa taksi dengan harga terjangkau.\"},{\"brand_city_id\": \"5\",\"name\": \"Cipaganti\",\"logo\": \"http://gojek.gits.co.id/uploads/Cipaganti.png\",\"description\": \"Bertemakan taksimax, Cipaganti Taksi bukan hanya sekedar pengantaran pelanggan di dalam kota, fasilitas lengkap adalah salah satu keunggulan taksimax ini. Dengan fasilitas Wi-Fi dan Movie serta kelengkapan kendaraan yang memadai telah membedakan layanan taksimax dengan taksi yang lainnya.\"}]";

         JSONArray jArray;
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(str);
             for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
                 Log.i("brand_city_id", jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("brand_city_id").toString()); 
                 Log.i("name", jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").toString()); 
                 Log.i("logo", jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("logo").toString()); 
                 Log.i("description", jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description").toString()); 
             }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This will help you to extract the image url, name etc. from the string. After extracting that you can load that to the listview. Hope it helps you..

Comment: where i must put the source ? sorry, i'm newbie :(

Comment: @DeniRohimat this source must be provide after the section where you get that json response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Now very simple with Glide image loader https://github.com/bumptech/glide

You just write this code

```
Glide.with(this).load(searchArrayList.get(position).getImageURI()).into(holder.image);
```